# PHP regex templateparser

Tags: php, regex

Dear programmers and code freaks,

I've got this function

```
<?php
function ListRow($name) {
    preg_match_all("'{row name ='".$name."'}(.*?){\/row}'si", $this->tpl, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
?>
```

What it is supposed to do is getting the info between `{row name = 'products'}` and `{/row}`.
It does get the data between the tags if they're on the same line, but with enters between
them, it doesn't capture anything. I'm kinda stuck in this one so i would appreciate some help
more then anything.

Comment: `preg_match_all` automatically matches new lines, so they shouldn't make any difference. Build an example for us here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This works, for me (see the "return" line, it's the only difference with your code...):

```
<?php

    print ListRow("abc");

    function ListRow($name) {
        preg_match_all("/{row name ='".$name."'(.*?){\/row}/si", "{row name ='abc'

TEXT_SEARCHED

{/row}", $match);
        return $match[1][0];
    }
?>
```

*And now, let's test it...:*

```
$ php test.php

TEXT_SEARCHED
```